# Angular2 template content store in variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a template (component.html) in angular2 and I want to read the content of the template and store in a variable so I can use it in the component.ts file.

Or

Is it possible to create a variable in a template (component.html) and store the content of the template in that variable and then use it in component.ts file

Comment: Its not real clear what you are asking. Can you provide a code sample of what you are trying to do?

Comment: are you talking about interpolation & data binding? https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----

Comment: If you have a <template> defined in your html and want to use it in the component you can have a look at something like ViewChild: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I have a angular2 template which has some html and two way binding variables in it. Now, in a different component I want to retrieve the content of this template. Once I have final content of this template I can use it to print. This is print funcitonality i am working on..

Comment: Hmm.. Still not sure I fully understand without some sort of example. But it sounds like maybe you are looking for transclusion. Here are some examples on this.. https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content ... & ...  https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html